# programming with Imperia templates

Tags: perl, templates, content-management-system

I am new to CMS imperia and looking for a good tutorial, how to programm with imperia templates. Any idea?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the provided programer documentation \imperia\documentation\de\imperia\program\program.pdf in the HTDOCS of your imperia CMS installation.

For a quick start do the following:

- create a simple metafile (to add common details about your document)
- create a simple template (first try an empty one)
- create a category and choose your metafile, template and the default workflow

then create a new document in that category

Which version do you use? (imperia 8, imperia 9 or imperia 10)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the WordPress Imperia theme? If so then it is used in the same way as any other WordPress theme, and you should take a look at the WordPress Codex documentation on [Using Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes).

Comment: no i mean imperia CMS http://www.imperia.net/index.html.en